# measureSpec returns wrong value

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get measured height of layout by using this code:

```
int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(toExpand.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        layoutHeight.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int height = layoutHeight.getMeasuredHeight();
```

it returns good values if I call it after layout has been created but I am also calling it on aplication startup when fragment gets attached and then it returns much higher values than expected.

Any ideas? Thanks in forward

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by using onGlobalLayout listener with viewTreeObserver. Here is the code:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = ((View) loadingLayout.getParent()).getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        ViewTreeObserver vto = ((View) loadingLayout.getParent()).getViewTreeObserver();
        int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(toExpand.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        layoutHeight.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int height = layoutHeight.getMeasuredHeight();
        if(toExpand.getHeight() == height){
            hide(toExpand, 0);
        }else{
            expand(toExpand, height);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            //deprecated od API level 16
            vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: have you figured out why  `measure` doesen't work outside `onGlobalLayout()`?